# Hibernate InheritanceType.JOINED Criteria Projection sum

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, inheritance, criteria

Im trying to sum value's on simular tables from multiple child classes using Hibernate Inheritance.

Using "@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)" on my parent class, and have multiple subclasses extending this. My problem is when I use Criteria with "Projections.sum" to get a result, Hibernate does a funny join.

Its as if hibernate takes the first matching result and does a summation on it - ignoring the rest, im not even sure if this can be done.

Hope my code below will clarify my problem.

**Animals - Parent class**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "animals")
public class Animals extends BaseObject{

    private Long animalId;
    private Long weight;
```

**Cats - Child class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cats")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="animal_id")
public class Cats extends Animals{

    private Long offspring;
    private String color;
```

**Dogs - Child class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dogs")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="animal_id")
public class Dogs extends Animals{

    private Long offspring;
    private String color;
    private int eggsLayed;
```

**Birds - Child class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "birds")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="animal_id")
public class Birds extends Animals {

    private Long offspring;
    private String color;
    private int eggsLayed;
```

**Fish - Child class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fish")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="animal_id")
public class Fish extends Animals {

    private Long offspring;
    private String color;
    private int eggsLayed;
```

**Criteria Query**

```
    ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.sum("eggsLayed"));

    Criteria crit = getSession()
            .createCriteria(Animals.class)
            .setProjection(projList);
```

**Related SQL output when running query:**

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        sum(this_3_.eggs_layed) as y0_ 
    from
        animals this_ 
    left outer join
        cats this_1_ 
            on this_.animal_id=this_1_.animal_id 
    left outer join
        dogs this_2_ 
            on this_.animal_id=this_2_.animal_id 
    left outer join
        birds this_3_ 
            on this_.animal_id=this_3_.animal_id 
    left outer join
        fish this_4_ 
            on this_.animal_id=this_4_.animal_id
```

Any feedback will be appreciated.